# How to set the Store View after login automatically for the whole session?

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, store-view

After logging into the backend and navigating to Catalog / Manage Products, the the dropdown "Choose store view" is set to "All Store Views" instead of the defined default Store View.

After changing the dropdown "Choose store view" to the desired Storeview the Store View is set.

How is it possible to set the Store View after login automatically for the whole session?

Answer (score 2):

So you cannot do this by default but what you could do, and sorry this is only concept, would be to expand on the admin user to add a new attribute for default store.

Then expand the store selector to read the default value from the user and set this value.

Not 100% sure how to code this but technically it should be possible just not sure how much effort it would be.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the default store view for an admin user for the whole session. However, what you can do is to set the store at the product grid level. A possible solution is to add a column called *default_store_id* to the table *admin_user* and then set the desired store id for each user. Next, override the method *_getStore()* in *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid*:

```
protected function _getStore()
{
    $storeId = (int) Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getDefaultStoreId();
    if (!$storeId) {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
    }   
    return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
}
```